# How much memory does Go take to compile dependencies and source code?

Tags: go, memory, memory-management, compilation

The problem I'm facing is that we have a docker container with 500MB RAM and 2CPU cores makes the compilation flaky. Sometimes it works and other times it doesn't. While the obvious solution is to increase the RAM memory we can't keep on increasing the memory.

Hence my question is, given a set of dependencies is it possible to pre-determine the memory needed to compile my go code and if so how?

While there is pprof, it seems it is to track the application memory.

The following results are taken from golangci-lint

Command executed:

```
golangci-lint run --issues-exit-code 1 --no-config --disable-all -E typecheck --enable=gosec --enable=unparam --enable=unconvert --enable=gocritic  --enable=ineffassign --enable=staticcheck --enable=dupl --enable=gocyclo --enable=gofmt --enable=golint --enable=deadcode --enable=errcheck --enable=gosimple --enable=govet --enable=structcheck --enable=typecheck --enable=unused --enable=varcheck
```

Results:

```
INFO File cache stats: 0 entries of total size 0B 
INFO Memory: 22 samples, avg is 58.7MB, max is 66.8MB 
INFO Execution took 2.063380705s
```

Comment: Practically, you can try running the compiler with various memory limits and see when it starts/stops working https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985

Comment: "we can't keep on increasing the memory" That's technically true but irrelevant.  It's 2022; 500 mb is not much memory.  Your memory consumption is not going to indefinitely grow by orders of magnitude.  Give your build environment more.  Your time is worth more to you than the minuscule cost of 500GB more.

Comment: here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPIB3STWXVk (> 30m) you can learn more about the tools around of the compiler. Mostly, you can memprofile the compile process and other thing. With the rest of the walkthrogh you can learn about the flags. So you could try some settigns setup to get that right for you. Though, a naive understanding, the system should swap pages to disk in order to take longer but to avoid OOM and thus increase success rate. It does not ? Also your report lacks details. You are showing the gitlab command line, it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

> [I]s it possible to pre-determine the memory needed to compile my go code [?]

No. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "predetermine" the memory requirements for the container.  Even if you knew exactly how much the go build process used, the container would use a different amount - think of file buffers and cache

One way to work out the optimum memory for compiling is to use a tool like https://github.com/facebookincubator/senpai which analyses the container under load.

Of course if the thing being compiled changes then it will need a different amount of memory but estimation is possible